# Unable to install breakpoint :Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

From last 1 week i am getting below exception in Eclipse kepler when running server in debug mode

[image]

But even after this exception breakpoints are working fine and even i deleted breakpoint which mentioned in this error but issue not resolved I saw one question [Eclipse Unable to install breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760856/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint) which saying some fixes but why this issue is coming from last 8years i never got this issue.

Any other quick fix for this?

Comment: Side note: tried updating to Eclipse Mars? It is not a "big jump", and even if this problem still exists, Mars has some advantages compared to the older versions of eclipse.

Comment: Are the working breakpoints in the same class or in other classes?

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760856/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957822/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to-missing-line-number-attributes) this is about remote debugging....

Comment: If the problematic class is generated dynamically (e.g. by the Spring framework), you have to consult the documentation of this framework how to enable the generation of debug information during compilation of these classes.

Comment: I can not use Mars because of this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262682/eclipse-mars-not-showing-jboss-server

Answer (score 0):

If the problematic class is generated dynamically (e.g. by the Spring framework), you have to consult the documentation of this framework how to enable the generation of debug information during compilation of these classes.

Comment: No class generating dynamically

Comment: Where does the (inner?) class "FastClassBySpringCGLIB..." come from? could you show the source code of this class?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi please also look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647114/how-to-know-the-line-of-a-bug-in-a-spring-generated-bean).

Comment: I am not using Spring in my project .